# Is it possible to automatically add a slug to an already existing URL once permalink structure has been changed?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

I am running a website in which the different posts all have an associated category: let's say, news, reviews, videos, etc.. We want to change how URLs are generated to incorporate the category before postname.
I will put an example:
old url: https:///www.myweb.com/amazing-new-car (with category in the post being news)
new url: https:///www.myweb.com/news/amazing-new-car (with category in the post being news)

I know how to do this by changing permalink structure in the wordpress settings to /%category%/%postname%/ but the problem is that this is applied to older entries too so when i try to access https:///www.myweb.com/amazing-new-car it gives me a 404 error. The problem here is that we have links to parts of our site sent to people, social networks and so and if they use them they will see this 404 error.

I've tried to use Redirection plugin to create a rule that can redirect old URLs to new URLs but it does not work (i've tried even wildcard redirection).

My question is: is there any way to do what i want rather than individual renaming of the links?

Thanks in advance, i hope i've explained well my problem

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has all the tools necessary to make this change happen, and typically it does successfully redirect the slug from /slug to /news/slug

**If you have added a category and haven't touched permalink settings, this is probably your problem.**
Once you add a new category or post type into Wordpress, you should go into the Permalink settings and just click save. No need to change the settings if you are happy with them...

Comment: Otherwise, if you are still experiencing an issue, using the code references below, a custom plugin could be made to combat this issue. Just don't code a redirect loop. Some logic to compare URLs would be needed.
   References: 
    https://njengah.com/get-post-id-by-slug-in-wordpress/
    https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/
    https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/